# Geometry Nodes. How to rotate object along with face angle

Tags: geometry-nodes, faces

I have oriented the cubes on faces with this node setup. But rotation is messed up. It keeps changing along the main object.
[image]

How can I orient the cubes so that the sides would be parallel to faces sides?

[image]

Comment: Could you attach your .blend file: https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=NK4mpES4" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/NK4mpES4/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mesh you're using has an order of indices that makes it possible to know what vertex or face is 'in front'.

Here we can see that the index of a following face is equal to the *index of the current face* plus $22$:

[image]

also, one of the vertices of a face has the same index as that face:

[image]

Knowing that, you can then use the position of a vertex of the next face subtracted by the position of a vertex of the current face to create a tangent vector, this vector is then used to align an axis using the previously aligned axis as pivot.

[image]

Result:

[image]

This is for this mesh specifically, if you need to do that for another mesh like this, it's probably a better idea to generate the mesh inside *Geometry Nodes* using curves, that way you could use the *Curve Tangent* node to get the direction.

Comment: Its Working! Thank a lot for detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

Might be useful for someone.
All you had to do was add one adjustment.

[image]

For 3.5.0 Alpha:

1. Variant one (Transfer Attribute -> Sample Nearest Surface)
   [image]
2. Variant two (Transfer Attribute -> Sample Index + Sample Nearest)
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using mesh to points?

Simply use the Distribute Points On Faces Node.

Maybe connecting the `Distribute Points On Faces` node's *Rotation* output to the *Rotation* input of the Euler Node will help?

[image]

Comment: Mesh to Points allow to place the cube on face.  Not on vertices.  Distribute Points On Faces is doing nothing in this setup. I've forgot to delete it.